# My program is having a problem detecting a specific letter inside a word

Tags: python

So I recently made a program where it detects a specific letter (n to be exact) inside a word given by the user.
(example: the program must detect a letter 'n' inside the word 'North')

But there is a slight problem, it cannot detect letter 'n' after the first letter of a word.
(example2: the program can detect 'Null' but not 'One')

Now, I tried editing the function, fixing the variables and conditional statements. But to no avail, nothing fixed it.

**Any help will be appreciated.**

Here is the code:

```
while True:

    def find_n(word):
        n_detector = ""
        for letter in word:
            if letter in 'Nn':
                print("I found letter(s) N in your given word: " + word)
                return n_detector

            else:
                print("I found no letter N in your given word: " + word)
                return n_detector


    print(find_n(input("Enter a word: ")))
```

Comment: Put the body of the else after the for loop :)

Comment: How? I am new to python. Sorry

Comment: remove else. You dont need that. Once you are out of the for loop, print the line and return n_detector. That will do. Thats what @Moosefeather meant.

Comment: @colappse Please accept one of the answers below (by clicking the check mark)

Comment: Okay, anyways thank you for your help everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to always return something if a function is called. You just leave it at print.

```
while True:

    def find_n(word):
        if ('n' in word.lower()):
            print("I found letter(s) N in your given word: " + word)
        else:
            print("I found no letter N in your given word: " + word)


    find_n(input("Enter a word: "))
```

A small point to mention- you do realize this loop will not end unless you interrupt the flow of the code? Be sure about it buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Your *specific* problem lies here:

```py
for letter in word:
    if letter in 'Nn':
        print("I found letter(s) N in your given word: " + word)
        return n_detector
    else:
        print("I found no letter N in your given word: " + word)
        return n_detector
```

In the *first* iteration of that loop (checking if the first letter is one of `nN`), it will print one of the messages and exit. It will *not* process the rest of the letters.

A modified construct that would check all letters would be:

```py
for letter in word:
    # Process each letter in word, returning if 'n' or 'N'.

    if letter in 'Nn':
        print("I found letter(s) N in your given word: " + word)
        return n_detector

    # This bit only runs after all letters processed and none were 'n' or 'N'.

    print("I found no letter N in your given word: " + word)
    return n_detector
```

But you can do it more efficiently by reversing what you're looking for. Rather than checking for each letter being in the string `'nN'`, you can check if `'n'` or `'N'` is in your *word.* This is a non-loop operation, at least as far as your concerned:

```py
if 'n' in word.lower():
    print("I found letter(s) N in your given word: " + word)
    return n_detector
print("I found no letter N in your given word: " + word)
return n_detector
```

---

I'm also not sure why you're returning an empty string regardless of what happens but that's not really relevant to the question at hand.

However, I'll modify your code so that it simply returns the string indicating whether `n/N` was found:

```py
def find_n(word):
    if 'n' in word.lower():
        return f"I found letter(s) N in your given word: {word}"
    return f"I found no letter N in your given word: {word}"

print(find_n(input("Enter a word: ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it as for-else:

```
Just make it as for-else:

while True:

    def find_n(word):
        n_detector = ""
        for letter in word:
            if letter in 'Nn':
                print("I found letter(s) N in your given word: " + word)
                return n_detector

        else:
            print("I found no letter N in your given word: " + word)
            return n_detector


    print(find_n(input("Enter a word: ")))
```

Or, Since you are returning in the if statement, You can remove your `else:`

```
while True:

    def find_n(word):
        n_detector = ""
        for letter in word:
            if letter in 'Nn':
                print("I found letter(s) N in your given word: " + word)
                return n_detector
        print("I found no letter N in your given word: " + word)
        return n_detector


    print(find_n(input("Enter a word: ")))
```

Answer (score -1):

6th Line you have done `if letter in 'Nn':` which means Nn both should be there so what you can do is `if letter.lower() in 'n':` this will convert the letter to lowercase and then compare.

So your code will look like:

```
while True:

    def find_n(word):
        n_detector = ""
        for letter in word:
            if letter.lower() in 'n':
                print("I found letter(s) N in your given word: " + word)
                return n_detector

            else:
                print("I found no letter N in your given word: " + word)
                return n_detector


    print(find_n(input("Enter a word: ")))
```

If you want more optimized code this is the one according to me:

```
while True:

    def find_n(word):
        n_detector = ""
        for letter in word:
            if letter in 'n':
                print("I found letter(s) N in your given word: " + word)

            else:
                print("I found no letter N in your given word: " + word)


    print(find_n(input("Enter a word: ").lower()))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go!

```
while True:

def find_n(word):
    n_detector = ""
    for letter in word:
        if letter in 'Nn':
            print("I found letter(s) N in your given word: " + word)
            return n_detector

        
    print("I found no letter N in your given word: " + word)
    return n_detector


print(find_n(input("Enter a word: ")))
```

**Explanation:**
The problem is with the `else` block. Why? Because for loop loops around the code written in it and no code is left after a complete iteration and then it comes back on the top and repeats the process. So in the very first iteration, it also runs the `else` block which if the first letter is not `n` or `N`. Thus not checking the rest of the letters.

Comment: This solution actually helped too. Thanks

Comment: Added this answer only for explanation as every other answer was directly providing the solution not the explanation why your code is not working.

Comment: Ifran, my own answer provided the exact reason why OPs code wasn't working and *then* went on to provide a solution. You may not have noticed that, it was only posted ten minutes before yours so it's possible we could have been answering in parallel. One thing I *did* notice is that the answers with downvotes all still use the inefficient method of looping over the character in the word to see if any of the characters is in `'Nn'`, rather than the better method of just seeing if `'n'` or `'N'` is in `word` (or, better again, if `'n'` is in `word.lower()`).

Comment: I just wanted to provide the reason why his code doesn't work. My code is not the ultimate solution i know.